# svg package in xelatex

Tags: graphics, xetex, svg

I'm using `\includesvg` from the `svg` package with `pdflatex`, which is very convenient. Unfortunately, when I try to use `xelatex`, this approach is not working any more. I'd like `xelatex` to have more options with font selection.

Any suggestions to carry on using `\includesvg` will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're just concerned about font selection you may also try `lualatex`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't say what error you got, this worked for me with `xelatex --shell-escape`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

a Á Γ →

\fbox{\includesvg{drawing.svg}}

\end{document}
```

In case you feel inspired by the artwork and wish to use it in your own documents, `drawing.svg` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   inkscape:version="0.92.1 r"
   sodipodi:docname="drawing.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="-154.28571"
     inkscape:cy="548.57143"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1001"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="29"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 39.008304,8.2621167 c -1.25992,-0.503968 -2.49242,-1.082791 -3.77976,-1.511903 -0.45353,-0.151178 -3.17655,0 -3.77977,0 -2.51984,0 -5.03968,0 -7.55952,0 -0.7097,0 -3.34661,-0.144386 -3.77976,0 -0.33807,0.112688 -0.43722,0.596582 -0.75595,0.755951 -0.22539,0.112692 -0.57778,-0.178181 -0.75596,0 -0.39842,0.398421 -0.35753,1.113483 -0.75595,1.511904 -0.92074,0.920739 -1.68896,0.354105 -2.26786,1.5119053 -0.93093,1.861873 2.19433,-0.6824233 -0.75595,2.267853 -0.39842,0.39843 -1.11348,0.35753 -1.5119,0.75596 -0.39842,0.39842 -0.50397,1.00793 -0.75596,1.5119 -0.25198,0.50397 -0.61929,0.96528 -0.75595,1.511911 -0.12223,0.48892 0.12223,1.022979 0,1.5119 -0.27331,1.09326 -1.09338,1.9775 -1.5119,3.02381 -0.2959397,0.73985 -0.4600097,1.52801 -0.7559597,2.26786 -0.20926,0.52315 -0.61929,0.96527 -0.75595,1.5119 -0.30557,1.2223 0.20713,2.53699 0,3.77976 -0.131,0.78601 -0.56269,1.49481 -0.75595,2.26786 -0.0611,0.24446 0.0611,0.51149 0,0.75595 -0.19326,0.77306 -0.59968,1.48649 -0.75595,2.26786 -0.0988,0.494181 0.12223,1.02298 0,1.5119 -0.13666,0.54664 -0.6193,0.96528 -0.75595,1.511909 -0.12223,0.488921 0,1.007941 0,1.511911 0,1.25992 0,2.519839 0,3.779761 0,3.527769 0,7.055548 0,10.583328 0,1.511911 0,3.023812 0,4.53572 0,0.50396 -0.0988,1.01772 0,1.511901 0.25198,0.755949 0.50396,1.511901 0.75595,2.26786 0.25198,0.251981 0.64326,0.41788 0.75595,0.755949 1.72985,5.189551 -2.8945,-3.521138 0.75595,3.779761 0.15937,0.318741 0.55828,0.459441 0.75595,0.755949 0.31255,0.468831 0.5039697,1.007941 0.7559597,1.511911 0.25198,0.50397 0.64545,0.95939 0.75595,1.511901 0,0.755959 0,1.511908 0,2.26786 0.25198,0.251978 0.64326,0.41788 0.75595,0.755949 0.15937,0.47811 -0.15937,1.033801 0,1.511911 0.22429,0.672849 2.04357,1.59499 2.26786,2.26785 0.15937,0.47811 -0.22538,1.06114 0,1.511908 0.11269,0.22538 0.5169,-0.0797 0.75595,0 0.53454,0.178181 1.11348,0.357532 1.51191,0.755952 0.17818,0.178178 -0.17818,0.57777 0,0.755949 1.41054,1.410549 2.21457,0.35134 3.02381,0.755951 0.31873,0.159369 0.50396,0.503968 0.75595,0.75596 0.86492,0.86492 0.89487,1.05424 2.26786,1.5119 0.4781,0.15937 1.00793,0 1.5119,0 1.76389,0 3.52778,0 5.29167,0 2.26785,0 4.53571,0 6.80357,0 0.75595,0 1.52658,0.14826 2.26786,0 1.39905,0.561499 1.38644,-1.29155 2.26785,-1.5119 0.73338,-0.183351 1.52659,0.148249 2.26786,0 3.04205,-0.60841 0.34733,-0.551641 2.26786,-1.511911 0.71272,-0.35636 1.48649,-0.599671 2.26786,-0.755949 2.883077,-0.57662 0.125698,1.071078 3.779758,-0.755952 0.318741,-0.159369 0.43721,-0.596588 0.755949,-0.755949 2.458701,-1.229349 1.798171,-0.190849 3.77976,-1.511911 0.296511,-0.197668 0.417881,-0.643258 0.75596,-0.755949 0.478099,-0.159369 1.02298,0.12223 1.511901,0 0.546629,-0.13666 1.00794,-0.50397 1.511911,-0.755949 0.50396,-0.251992 1.043077,-0.44341 1.511898,-0.755952 0.593021,-0.395348 0.874432,-1.19317 1.5119,-1.511908 0.225391,-0.112692 0.577782,0.178178 0.75596,0 0.39842,-0.39842 0.443399,-1.04308 0.755952,-1.511901 0.19767,-0.29651 0.503967,-0.50397 0.755949,-0.755959 0.251989,-0.251982 0.437221,-0.59658 0.755948,-0.755952 0.225391,-0.112689 0.546291,0.139782 0.755963,0 4.383079,-2.922058 0.559779,-0.36362 1.511898,-2.26786 0.159371,-0.318738 0.50397,-0.503968 0.755951,-0.755949 0.503971,-0.503971 1.084279,-0.941729 1.511909,-1.511901 1.85701,-0.269549 0.313941,-1.604848 0.755951,-2.26786 0.395349,-0.593018 1.084271,-0.941729 1.511909,-1.511908 0.338071,-0.450761 0.41788,-1.061141 0.755952,-1.511901 0.641448,-0.85526 1.674839,-1.378331 2.26786,-2.26786 2.201098,-3.301651 -0.33505,0.249179 0.755949,-3.023809 0.112688,-0.338072 0.50396,-0.503971 0.755949,-0.755952 0,-0.503968 -0.12223,-1.02298 0,-1.511909 -0.455639,-1.368221 1.2246,-1.405929 1.5119,-2.267849 0.23345,-0.70032 -0.24145,-3.055401 0,-3.779761 0.178192,-0.53454 0.6193,-0.965279 0.75596,-1.511911 0.17132,-0.6853 0,-2.90159 0,-3.779758 0,-0.603221 0.15117,-3.326231 0,-3.779761 -0.356359,-1.069081 -1.238589,-1.930551 -1.511909,-3.023809 -0.122229,-0.488921 0.12223,-1.022991 0,-1.511911 -0.131529,-0.52613 -0.853241,-1.93852 -1.5119,-2.26785 -0.22538,-0.11269 -0.577771,0.17818 -0.755949,0 -0.178192,-0.17818 0,-0.50397 0,-0.75596 -0.251992,-0.50396 -0.357542,-1.11348 -0.755962,-1.5119 -0.35636,-0.35636 -1.155539,0.35636 -1.511898,0 -0.356362,-0.35636 0.356359,-1.15554 0,-1.5119 -0.178181,-0.17819 -0.530572,0.11268 -0.755952,0 -1.67146,-0.83573 -0.23459,-0.46918 -0.75596,-1.51191 -1.57304,-3.14609 0.0522,0.80814 -1.5119,-0.75595 -0.178179,-0.178181 0.178181,-0.57778 0,-0.75595 -0.0469,-2.12857 -1.704409,-0.1925 -2.26786,-0.75596 -0.178179,-0.17818 0.112691,-0.53057 0,-0.75595 -0.159369,-0.31874 -0.503968,-0.50397 -0.755949,-0.755951 -0.251982,-0.251979 -0.437222,-0.596589 -0.755949,-0.755959 -0.22538,-0.11268 -0.577782,0.17819 -0.755963,0 -0.178167,-0.17817 0.178181,-0.57777 0,-0.75595 -0.39842,-0.398421 -0.977357,-0.57777 -1.511897,-0.75595 -0.239052,-0.0797 -0.577771,0.17818 -0.755952,0 -0.178178,-0.17818 0,-0.503971 0,-0.75595 -0.251989,-0.25199 -0.459449,-0.558281 -0.75596,-0.75595 -0.46882,-0.312551 -1.04308,-0.443411 -1.5119,-0.755961 -0.68815,-0.45876 -1.59783,-1.93284 -2.26786,-2.26785 -0.22538,-0.11269 -0.530569,0.11269 -0.755949,0 -0.637472,-0.31874 -0.87443,-1.19317 -1.511901,-1.51191 -0.225391,-0.11269 -0.53058,0.11269 -0.75596,0 -0.31873,-0.15937 -0.43721,-0.59658 -0.755949,-0.75595 -0.22538,-0.11269 -0.530571,0.11269 -0.755951,0 -0.637479,-0.31874 -0.87443,-1.193169 -1.511909,-1.5119043 -0.410091,-0.20505 -2.81696,0.206843 -3.023812,0 -0.178167,-0.178181 0.178181,-0.577773 0,-0.755954 -0.356359,-0.35636 -1.155538,0.356359 -1.511897,0 -0.178181,-0.178179 0.178178,-0.577771 0,-0.755952 -0.178181,-0.178178 -0.503971,0 -0.755949,0 -0.25199,0 -0.50397,0 -0.75596,0 -2.51984,0 -5.03968,0 -7.55952,0 z"
       id="path3680"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 21.621394,31.696638 c -0.50396,1.00794 -1.09338,1.977501 -1.5119,3.023809 -0.18717,0.467931 0,1.007941 0,1.511911 0,0.395301 -0.0994,2.825041 0,3.023809 0.15937,0.318741 0.50397,0.503971 0.75595,0.755952 0.25199,0.251978 0.43722,0.59658 0.75595,0.755949 0.19877,0.0994 2.62851,0 3.02381,0 0.39531,0 2.82504,0.0994 3.02381,0 3.14609,-1.573041 -0.80814,0.0522 0.75595,-1.511901 0.17818,-0.178178 0.64327,0.22538 0.75596,0 0.30238,-0.604769 -0.30238,-1.663099 0,-2.26786 0.15936,-0.318738 0.59658,-0.437219 0.75595,-0.755949 0.22538,-0.45076 -0.22538,-1.061141 0,-1.511911 0.15937,-0.318738 0.59658,-0.437208 0.75595,-0.755949 0.0994,-0.198771 0,-2.6285 0,-3.02381 0,-0.34045 0.11503,-2.03779 0,-2.26786 -0.15937,-0.31873 -0.59658,-0.43721 -0.75595,-0.75595 -0.11269,-0.22538 0.17818,-0.57777 0,-0.75595 -0.17818,-0.17818 -0.50397,0 -0.75595,0 -1.51191,0 -3.02381,0 -4.53572,0"
       id="path3682"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 45.055924,33.208549 c 0,1.511898 0,3.023809 0,4.53571 0,0.525798 -0.13669,3.506388 0,3.779768 1.57305,3.146092 -0.0522,-0.808148 1.5119,0.755952 0.17819,0.178178 -0.17817,0.577768 0,0.755949 0.17819,0.178181 0.50397,0 0.75596,0 0.251978,0 0.503967,0 0.755949,0 0.525787,0 3.50638,0.136689 3.779758,0 3.146099,-1.573051 -0.808138,0.0522 0.755951,-1.511901 0.178179,-0.178189 0.530569,0.112681 0.75596,0 0.658659,-0.32934 1.380371,-1.741728 1.5119,-2.26786 0.006,-0.02529 -0.004,-2.263838 0,-2.26786 0.178179,-0.178178 0.643261,0.22538 0.755949,0 0.22538,-0.45076 0,-1.00793 0,-1.511909 0,-1.259911 0,-2.51984 0,-3.77976 0,-0.25198 0,-0.50396 0,-0.75595 0,-0.25198 0.178181,-0.57777 0,-0.75595 -0.178181,-0.17818 -0.530569,0.11269 -0.755949,0 -0.31874,-0.15937 -0.43721,-0.59658 -0.755951,-0.75595 -0.22538,-0.11269 -0.577771,0.17818 -0.755949,0 -0.178181,-0.17818 0.178178,-0.57778 0,-0.75596 -0.498041,-0.49804 -1.01387,0.49804 -1.511911,0 -0.178179,-0.17818 0.178181,-0.57777 0,-0.75595 -0.178179,-0.17818 -0.503971,0 -0.755949,0 -0.251982,0 -0.503971,0 -0.755949,0 -0.403842,0 -3.563409,-0.10818 -3.779769,0 -0.31873,0.15937 -0.50396,0.50397 -0.75595,0.75595"
       id="path3684"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 45.055924,33.208549 c -9.49144,11.526179 -9.82738,8.330798 -9.82738,15.119048 l -1.51191,9.07143"
       id="path3686"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 11.038064,69.494259 c 2.01587,-1.25992 3.96956,-2.625281 6.04762,-3.779761 1.29592,-0.71995 0.46797,0.467971 0.75595,0.755949 0.17818,0.178181 0.53057,-0.112689 0.75595,0 3.1461,1.573051 -0.80814,-0.0522 0.75596,1.511911 0.17817,0.178181 0.57777,-0.178181 0.75595,0 1.00794,1.00793 -1.25992,0.755949 0.75595,0.755949 0.18334,0 2.24355,-0.02429 2.26786,0 0.17818,0.178181 -0.17818,0.577771 0,0.755952 0.17818,0.178178 0.50396,0 0.75595,0 1.25992,0 2.51984,0 3.77976,0 3.02381,0 6.04762,0 9.07143,0 0.25199,0 0.50397,0 0.75595,0 0.25199,0 0.57778,0.178178 0.75596,0 0.17818,-0.178181 -0.17818,-0.577771 0,-0.755952 0.35636,-0.356359 1.06114,0.22538 1.5119,0 0.31874,-0.159369 0.43722,-0.59658 0.75595,-0.755949 0.45077,-0.22538 1.06114,0.22538 1.51191,0 0.31874,-0.159369 0.43721,-0.59659 0.75595,-0.75596 0.60476,-0.302371 1.6631,0.30239 2.26786,0 3.146088,-1.57304 -0.80814,0.0522 0.75595,-1.5119 0.35636,-0.35636 1.15555,0.356359 1.51191,0 0.178178,-0.178181 -0.17818,-0.577771 0,-0.755949 1.007927,-1.007941 0.755949,1.259919 0.755949,-0.755952"
       id="path3700"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Oh man, there's just absurd amounts of bloat in Inkscape-generated SVGs.

Comment: @morbusg true but the result is a work of pure art, don't you agree?

Comment: Yes, I do agree. +1 for that alone :) the title of the work brings an air of enigma.

Comment: Could  not get running includesvg with xelatex with inkscape generated files. So I returned to pdflatex which works flawlessly. Thank you for the advice anyway!